# Need help filtering an excel sheet for determined conditions

Tags: excel

Hi I'm having an issue with filtering an excel sheet. Basically I'm extracting a very long pdf to excel.

From the data exported I'm only interested in some codes that come in the form of SM12345 (SM and five numbers).

I was able to create a formula in excel to check for 3 conditions I defined to filter the data but it only check on a single cell value(I can't seem to find how to refer to the whole sheet as range, as in the search function).

My idea is to use advance filtering and use my 3 conditions as criteria but I don't know how to refer to the whole sheet in excel, so then I record a macro and copy those in a separate column.

My conditions are:

1- Contains "SM"

2- The length is 7 (though I think I could use wild characters after SM, not sure)

3- The string contains numbers

This is the excel formula I have for a single cell:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sm",A9)),LEN(A9)=7,COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A9))>0),A9,"")
```

Comment: Why don't you copy that formula down the whole column of data?

Comment: Because they might be spread in different columns. Is there a way to pass the whole sheet as argument instead of a single cell value when using the search function?

Comment: Don't think you can do that without VBA.

Comment: If you are searching only limited columns you could cover several columns using OR.

Comment: I guess I could with VBA but my knowledge there is limited

Comment: You may want to consider exporting the PDF to text, cleaning up the text in a good text editor (with some regular expressions) and then bringing the data in Excel

Comment: I dont know how good a text editor could be, like in the sense of keeping the order of the matches. Ideally I could loop through every row checking every cell value and if a matches occurs copy that value in a different column, but I have no idea how  to put that into vba

Answer (score 0):

First find all SM* and select them all with ctrl+a in the find box as shown in the image. After closing the find box all the cells will remain selected and then you can run the following macro. Then you can do anything with those cells looping myRng.

```
Sub SlectCond()
Dim myRng As Range
For Each cell In Selection
     If HasNumber(cell.Value) And Len(cell) >= 7 Then
        If myRng Is Nothing Then
        Set myRng = cell
        Else
        Set myRng = Union(myRng, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next

For Each cell In myRng
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Next

End Sub

Function HasNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
 Dim iCnt As Integer
 For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
    HasNumber = True
    Exit Function
    End If
 Next iCnt
End Function
```

[image]

Or if you want to execute all through a macro........

```
Sub SlectCond()

Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select

Dim myString, myStringArr
myString = ""

Dim myRng As Range
For Each cell In Selection
     If HasNumber(cell.Value) And InStr(1, cell.Value, "SM") And Len(cell) >= 7 Then
        If myRng Is Nothing Then
        Set myRng = cell
        myString = cell.Value
        Else
        Set myRng = Union(myRng, cell)
        myString = myString & "," & cell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next

For Each cell In myRng
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Next

myStringArr = Split(myString, ",")

Worksheets.Add
For i = 0 To UBound(myStringArr)
Range("A" & i + 1) = myStringArr(i)
Next


End Sub

Function HasNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
 Dim iCnt As Integer
 For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
    HasNumber = True
    Exit Function
    End If
 Next iCnt
End Function
```

Comment: One can also use Range.Find

Comment: I managed to do some vba, but I'm getting an error, could you help.                 Sub IterateCells()
    
    Dim positionofSubstring, i, newstring As Integer
    Dim lmname      As Long
    
    i = 1
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        positionofSubstring = InStr(1, cell.Value, "SM")
        newstring = Mid(cell.Value, positionofSubstring, 7)
        lmname = Val(newstring)
        
        If IsNumeric(lmname) Then
            Range("Wi").Value = lmname
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
End Sub

Comment: Can you post two things? First, image of your excel screen and second how would you like your results.

Comment: Your second code works great, how would you then copy all those occurrences into a separate column keeping the order of appearing? Thanks.

Comment: edited my answer.. new sheet will be added with the list

Comment: If this answers your question, please upvote/accept the answer and close the question. So that, others will know.